# Implementation of Tree Kernels in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, statistics, nlp

I'm looking to use a tree kernel (e.g. Zelenko et al., 2003, Moschitti 2006, etc.) for text classification in Python. However, I'm still a little unclear on the implementation. Is there an existing implementation (in any language) that I could use as a reference, or is there a 3rd-party tree kernel library I could use?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the ones from [here](http://joedsm.altervista.org/pythontreekernels.htm) are Moschitti's version, as the author is associated with Moschitti in some papers. I'm unable to confirm, though.